# Javascript not supported in SAP WebdynPro or WebGUI. How can a canvas app subscribe in that situation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am in a position trying to submit a Canvas POC to the client. But the issue is Javascript not supported in SAP WebdynPro or WebGUI. How to subscribe to visualforce events from canvas events in that situation where the Canvas Application does not support javascript? Any alternate approach available if canvas app does not support javascript?